# java script index Of not case senstive

Tags: javascript, indexof, case-insensitive

I have this code:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('myTextarea');
var tag = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
var textValue = textarea.value;

if (textValue.indexOf(tag) != -1) {
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "match found";
} else {
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "no match found";
}
```

I’m trying to get `indexOf` to match tag no matter if the `var` tag is in upper-case or lower-case. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: How about putting your `tag` variable and your `textValue` variable to lower case before comparing them ?

Comment: Convert all the content to either lowecase or uppercase and keep the same case for search string also. something like textValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(tag.toUpperCase()) !=-1

Comment: thank you this has work perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `toUpperCase()` like this

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('myTextarea');
var tag = '<!DOCTYPE html>';  
var textValue=textarea.value;

if (textValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(tag.toUpperCase())!=-1)
{
   document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "match found";
} else {
       document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "no match found";
}
```

This way the condition compares both as upper case even if one of them is lower case, hence case insensitive

Comment: thank you this has work perfectly

Comment: You're Welcome :)